# How can i automatically reload karma-html-reporter

Tags: testing, jasmine, karma-runner, karma-jasmine

I just started testing with Karma. When i specify a browser in the config-file it basically just opens a window that tells me that the test is idle or running, nothing more and nothing less. That doesn't make sense to me, why would i need a browser for that? Okay i get it you need to debug but thats another page where you can debug isn't it?

[image]

Although this site is reloading when Karma is doing something, the other , way more usefull, `karma-html-reporter` output stays like it is until i reload it manually.

Is there any way to either

- **(A) Show the test ouput in a html-reporter like fashion on the `connected`-page?**

or

- **(B) Connect the `html-reporter`-page to the socket and live-reload it?**

I know i can just use the console, but isn't it nice to have some order and styling in all the chaos?